# Router Problem in React App, can't resolve it

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Using react-router-dom, but getting this "Cannot destructure property 'basename' of 'react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.useContext(...)' as it is null."

```
import "./App.css";
import Navbar from "./components/Navbar";
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";

import Home from "./Pages/Home/Home";
import Contact from "./Pages/Contact/Contact";
import About from "./Pages/About/About";

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Navbar />
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Home />} exact />
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Can't resolve it.

I tried to create a router file, separeted from App.js.
Even remade this project. But still getting this error

Comment: Already made it.

Comment: Can you show your index.js file structure as well? Also, put "exact" before path I believe.

Answer (score 0):

Only issue I see is the navbar being rendered outside the router. The `BrowserRouter` provides a routing context that all RRD components (`Links`, `Routes`, `Route`, etc) all consume.

Move the `Navbar` component inside the `BrowserRouter` so it is able to consume the routing context it provides.

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Navbar />
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}
```